# Cytoscape expandcollapse events not getting triggered

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

I am using **Angular 4** and **Cytoscape.js** library to draw graphs. I added  **cytoscape.js-expand-collapse** extension to implement expand and collapse feature on compound nodes. Although the nodes get expanded and collapsed, I am not able to listen to their events. Below are the events I want to listen to:

```
cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforecollapse", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) Triggered before a node is collapsed

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.aftercollapse", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) Triggered after a node is collapsed

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforeexpand", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) Triggered before a node is expanded

cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.afterexpand", function(event) { var node = this; ... }) Triggered after a node is expanded
```

Sharing my code snippet below:

```
// imported cytoscape, cytoscape-expand-collapse, etc
//Create instance of cytoscape:
this.cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),

      layout: {
        name: 'grid',
        avoidOverlap: true,
        padding: 30
      }
})

// added nodes to the cy instance using cy.add

// use expandcollapse extension:
this.cy.expandCollapse({
      layoutBy:null,
      fisheye: false,
      animate: false,
      undoable: false,
      zIndex: 0
    });

//listen to events:
this.cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforecollapse", (event) => { 
      console.log('1+');
     }) //Triggered before a node is collapsed

    this.cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.aftercollapse", (event) => { 
      console.log('2+') }) //Triggered after a node is collapsed

    this.cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.beforeexpand", (event) => { 
      console.log('3+') }) //Triggered before a node is expanded

    this.cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse.afterexpand", (event) => { 
      console.log('4+') })
```

Although expansion-collapse work, the above events don't trigger. Is there something which I am missing here ?

Comment: Adding the listener on the core instance worked for me i.e replaced this.cy.nodes().on("expandcollapse..." with this.cy.on("expandcollapse.."